# Monitor CoreOS with icinga

Tags: nagios, coreos, icinga

I need to monitor a CoreOS cluster which used to host a kubernetes cluster on top of that. I use heapster to monitor kuberenetes cluster.

Now I need to monitor CoreOS minions using icinga/nagios. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Did you aware of nrpe?

Comment: yes but in coreos you cannot install nrpe from package managers right?

Comment: can you try with source compilation??

Answer (score -1):

If *CoreOS* is similar enough to *Linux*, it will likely be compatible with *NRPE* or *NCPA*.

I would try this first...

**NRPE install**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/agents/linux-nrpe-agent.tar.gz
tar xzf linux-nrpe-agent.tar.gz
cd linux-nrpe-agent
./fullinstall
```

Is *yum*, *rpm*, or any other package manager present on *CoreOS*? Sorry I'm a bit unfamiliar with the OS...